# Retrieving multiple values from a for-loop into a separate function to compare

Tags: c, function, for-loop

I've been tasked to compare values in a for-loop by using function declaration. However, I'm stuck in doing so. My approach only allows the program to retrieve the latest value in a for-loop. How do I make my function store 5 numbers from the for-loop to compare ?

My assignments:

1. Input total covid cases and population for 5 countries
2. Calculate the average cases per 100,000 people in the country
3. Compare the 5 average number and see which is the biggest [Use a function to do this]

   ```
   for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
            printf("Input total number of COVID cases for 1 country: ");
            scanf("%d", &cases);
            printf("Input total population for 1 country: ");
            scanf("%d", &population);
            average = cases / (population / 100000);
            biggest(average);  
        }

    int biggest(int average)
    {
        int biggest=0;
        if (average > biggest)
        {
            biggest = average;
            printf("Biggest value is %d", biggest);
        }
        return biggest;
    }
   ```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVc8d.png)

Comment: What about arrays?

Comment: Also, you declare `biggest` to return an `int` value but don't actually return anything. Perhaps its return-type should be `void` instead? Or return `biggest` (which you need to take care of in the loop where you call the function).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My professor hasn't taught array yet. He say is possible to do with just using function. Help

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hmm... I can give it a try

Comment: Your professor doesn't want you to return multiple values but compare 5 values and return the biggest number of it.

Comment: @Raildex Nono. We did it in the normal comparison, which is to input the if-else in the for-loop. Now he want us to produce the same output but by using a separate function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete assignment you have, including any and all requirements and limitations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay hold on

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and please don't post text as a screenshot. Yes, you can copy from the command line window. -- Implement a solution that works without a function. Then identify the part to be extracted, its parameters, and if necessary its return value. Then extract the function.

Comment: First of all, while you need to compare the current average with the currently biggest average inside the loop, you can't display it until *after* the loop. As for the comparison you need a typical "max" kind of function where you return the max of two numbers (as in `if (a > b) { return a; } else { return b; }`). Then you use it like `biggest = max(average, biggest);`. And after the loop print the value of `biggest`.

Comment: @thebusybee Okay I will take note next time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Interesting..